# How to return multiple parsed ADTs in Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using Parsec to parse a file that looks like this:

```
## public_id

ANALOG-CLOCK

## name

Analog Wall Clock
Some more text...

## domain

Time measurement

More text here...
```

except that the file can have a variable number of sections, where each section starts with a "## " line and may contain 0+ content lines.

```
type Model = [Section]

data Section = Section String [String]
               deriving Show


headingLine :: Parser String
headingLine = do
  try (string "##")
  spaces
  title <- many1 (noneOf "\r\n")
  char '\n'
  return title


nonHeadingLine :: Parser String
nonHeadingLine = do
  try (noneOf "#")
  contents <- many1 (noneOf "\r\n")
  char '\n'
  return contents


section :: Parser Section
section = do
  title <- headingLine
  contentLines <- many1 nonHeadingLine
  spaces
  return $ Section title contentLines


model :: Parser Model
model = do
  s1 <- section
  s2 <- section
  s3 <- section
  return [s1, s2, s3]
  --return $ many1 section


main :: IO ()
main = do
  modelStr <- readFile "analog3.md"
  let result = do parse model "" modelStr
  case result of
    Left  err -> putStrLn $ "Error " ++ show err
    Right mdl -> putStrLn $ show mdl
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
[Section "public_id" "ANALOG-CLOCK",Section "name" "Analog Wall Clock",Section "domain" "Time measurement"]
```

The code works when I have exactly one content line per section and produces the above output.

I have two problems:

1) The code doesn't work when I have more than one content line per section, and

2) When I use `return $ many1 section` instead of `return [s1, s2, s3]`, I get a type error "Couldn't match type ‘Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Section]’ with ‘[Section]’ ".

How do I get it to handle more than one content line and how do I get it to process more than one section? Thanks.

Comment: `many1` is already a monadic type, so you do not need to use `return` with it. Just type `many1 section`. "return" is not a keyword in Haskell; it is a function that embeds a value in a monad: `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`

Comment: Thanks! That gets rid of the type error, but I get a runtime error of "Error (line 12, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting white space or "##"  ". I have the feeling that I'm not separating/terminating sections properly, but I don't know how I should.

Comment: @citrus That seems like it's running `headingLine` at the end of the file, after the whole thing has been parsed already. If you now have `many1 section` at the end of your `model` function, but you forgot to remove the previous four lines, that would cause it to try to parse at least four sections, when there are only three.

Comment: @DarthFennec: Thanks, that worked! I forgot to remove the other lines.